Excel drop-down list : problem changing the selected option
I have an issue with excel. I created a drop-down list and here are my problems :

when I select one of the option, a semi-colon is added at the end



when I want to change the selected option, it only adds it before the 1st one with a semi-colon, instead of replacing it.



I found the solution so thought I would post it in case it can help.
I opened the code editor and, for some reason, in the Change event, the code read :
xStrNew = xStrNew & " ; " & Target.Value

I then changed it to
xStrNew = xStrNew

And it worked ...
